# nagios: why this error?

Tags: nagios

My kdc plugin works fine

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kdc -H samba4 -p nagios/nagios1.mydom.priv@MYDOM.PRIV -k /etc/nagios/nagios.keytab 
OK
```

But give me this error on webpage

```
(Return code of 13 for service 'KDC' on host 'samba4' was out of bounds)
```

this is the cfg

commands.cfg

```
define command{
        command_name    check_kdc
        command_line    /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kdc -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -k $ARG1$ -p $ARG2$
        }
```

mydom.cfg

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       samba4
        service_description             KDC
        check_command                   check_kdc!/etc/nagios/nagios.keytab!nagios/nagios1.mydom.priv@MYDOM.PRIV
        notifications_enabled           1
        }
```

Why nagios return error 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
Was only a permission problem.

```
    chown -Rc root:nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins
    chmod -c 750 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kdc
```

Comment: The fundamental issue was that your original permissions were completely messed up, you had given "other" permission to execute but not read the file which doesn't make any sense. Changing that from 751 to 755 does fix the issue, but the proper way to set this up is to have the plugin be owned by something like `root:nagios` so that you can set permission 750 and give others (i.e. not nagios users) no permissions at all.

Comment: Good. Add this comment as answer so I can select it as solution

Comment: That's OK, your answer isn't technically wrong, it's just that it's good to think about what permissions you set and why. If you want, you can use the information in my comment to edit your answer.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Thanks for advice

Comment: @pzkpfw "execute but not read" like 111 is quite useful secure setting. It is absolutely not "wrong", it's rather "uncommon". It is perfectly sensible and works exactly as you'd expect: any user can run the executable, but nobody can, say, copy it, or extract strings and so on. Try it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it is wrong, because "execute without read" only works for binaries. We are specifically talking about Nagios plugins here, and a setup where 100% of the Nagios plugins are binaries is in my experience extremely uncommon. In this specific example 'check_kdc' is indeed not a binary but a bash script.

Comment: I did not check this specific plugin, and you're right, scripts need read privilege to be executed. Not 100%, but binary Nagios plugins are surprisingly common. Still, "no read but execute" makes sense, just not in this particular case. That was too general statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` character in your `check_command`

Reference: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-xi-special-characters-580.html

Comment: Thanks, was only a permission problem, no need to modify my conf. files